# How to manually place tickmarks in a png with \addplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a very large matlab figure which I would like to integrate to latex via tikzpictures. The size of the file prevents me from externalizing it, so I save it as a png and want to include it into my tex-file via \addplot.

Here is what I have so far as an MWE with the figMinimalExample added below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false, 
                 axis on top,
                 width=\textwidth,
                 xlabel={$F_1$},
                 ylabel={$\Sigma_{X_3}$}
                  ]
    \addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=8,ymin=0.662,ymax=0.674] {figMinimalExample.png};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{efe}





\end{document}
```

The picture to be added is:

[image: This is figMinimalExample.png]

What I got from compiling is

[image]

The thing is that the original plot runs from x=[0,8], but I would firstly like to manually place the tick marks and instead of having numbers running from 0 to 8 in the figure, I would rather have 0 at the first tick and then $\hat{mu}$ or something instead of the 8.

I tried adding

```
 xticklabels={0, \phantom{0},  \phantom{0} , \phantom{0} ,  2, 3, 4+}
```

to the axis environment, just for trying, but it did not turn out as desired. Does anybody have an idea?

Also, I found that the number of ticks placed in the figure depends on the size of the figure in the final document. I would possibly like to have the same ticks allocation independent of figure size.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me (xtick to specify where to place ticks, xticklabels to specify the label texts):

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false, 
                 axis on top,
                 width=\textwidth,
                 xlabel={$F_1$},
                 ylabel={$\Sigma_{X_3}$},
                 xtick={0,2,4,8},
                 xticklabels={0,$\sfrac{\hat\mu}4$,$\sfrac{\hat\mu}2$,$\hat\mu$}
                  ]
    \addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=8,ymin=0.662,ymax=0.674] {figMinimalExample.png};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: raster image of above example]

Comment: Cool - I believe, this pretty much is it. Thank you, you helped me a lot!!!